# C# to VB.Net conversion issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-to-vb.net

when converting the following line from C# to VB.Net I get

**Expression does not produce a value**

C#

```
query.ToList().ForEach(ti => cat.Add(ti));
```

VB.NET

```
query.ToList().ForEach(Function(ti) cat.Add(ti))
```

---

C# code :

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new DesignerMetadata().Register();

    var toolbox = new ToolboxControl();
    var cat = new ToolboxCategory("Standard Activities");
    var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
    assemblies.Add(typeof(Send).Assembly);
    assemblies.Add(typeof(Delay).Assembly);
    assemblies.Add(typeof(ReceiveAndSendReplyFactory).Assembly);

    var query = from asm in assemblies
                from type in asm.GetTypes()
                where type.IsPublic &&
                !type.IsNested &&
                !type.IsAbstract &&
                !type.ContainsGenericParameters &&
                (typeof(Activity).IsAssignableFrom(type) ||
                typeof(IActivityTemplateFactory).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                orderby type.Name
                select new ToolboxItemWrapper(type);

    query.ToList().ForEach(ti => cat.Add(ti));
    toolbox.Categories.Add(cat);
    Grid.SetColumn(toolbox, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(toolbox, 1);
    LayoutGrid.Children.Add(toolbox);
}
```

I want Vb.net conversion. when i converted this code in vb.net getting error in query.ToList().ForEach(Function(ti) cat.Add(ti)) this line .error is Expression does not produce a value.

Converted VB.NET code

```
  Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim metadata = New DesignerMetadata()
    metadata.Register()

    'Create the ToolBoxControl
    Dim toolbox = New ToolboxControl()

    'Create a collection of category items
    Dim cat = New ToolboxCategory("Standard Activities")
    Dim assemblies = New List(Of Assembly)()
    assemblies.Add(GetType(SendAndReceiveReplyFactory).Assembly)
    assemblies.Add(GetType(Delay).Assembly)
    assemblies.Add(GetType(ReceiveAndSendReplyFactory).Assembly)

    Dim query = _
     From asm In assemblies
     From type In asm.GetTypes() _
     Where type.IsPublic AndAlso Not type.IsNested AndAlso Not type.IsAbstract AndAlso Not type.ContainsGenericParameters AndAlso (GetType(Activity).IsAssignableFrom(type) OrElse GetType(IActivityTemplateFactory).IsAssignableFrom(type)) _
     Order By type.Name
     Select New ToolboxItemWrapper(type)

    query.ToList().ForEach(Function(ti) cat.Add(ti))
    toolbox.Categories.Add(cat)
    Grid.SetColumn(toolbox, 0)
    Grid.SetRow(toolbox, 1)
    LayoutGrid.Children.Add(toolbox)
End Sub
```

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear where the error is, you should try to only include the relevant bits of information in your questions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the problematic line to that one:

```
query.ToList().ForEach(Sub(ti) cat.Add(ti))
```

That's necessary because there is a separate syntax for `Action<T>` (`Sub(T)`) and `Func<T>` (`Function(t)`) in VB.NET (but there is not in C#).